# working perl ascript now says .DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, perl

I got this perl script and it used to work fine till recently.
i am getting this error message.

DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your                                             MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=''' at line 2 at import_productfeatures.pl line 71.
DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL serve                                            r version for the right syntax to use near ' '')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=''' at line 2 at import_productfeatures.pl line 71.

```
foreach my $feature (@features) {
    my $cat_featureid = $feature->{CategoryFeature_ID};
    my $value = $feature->{Presentation_Value};
    my $sql = "INSERT INTO products_features (product_id, feature_id, value) 
        VALUES (".$prodid.", ".$cat_featureid.", ".$dbh->quote($value).") 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=".$dbh->quote($value);
    $dbh->do($sql);
  }
```

Comment: i just realised the scripts works  if i parse a single  file .i also tested it with 100 files and it works.But it tends to throw the error in the end when i ask it to do all 65222  files.Can it be a  time out issue..i dont know much about perl.

Comment: Learn how to use prepared statements.

Comment: 65222 is close to 65535, the largest 16-bit unsigned int. Maybe there's some kind of resource leak? What if you reconnect to the DB every 10,000 requests?

Answer (score 6):

You should use placeholders, instead of putting the values directly into the string:

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO products_features (product_id, feature_id, value) 
   VALUES (?,?,?) 
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=?";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

foreach my $feature (@features) {
    my $cat_featureid = $feature->{CategoryFeature_ID};
    my $value = $feature->{Presentation_Value};

    $sth->execute($prodid,$cat_featureid,$value,$value);
}

$sth->finish();
```

DBI will handle the correct escaping for you.

Comment: Even better, $dbh->prepare the statement outside of the loop.

Comment: You're right. That will be a performance boost. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 3):

Print out the value of `$sql` so you can see the SQL statement that you are building.  Then you can see what the syntax problem is, or post it here so we can diagnose it.

However, even more than that, you should be using parametrized queries, not building SQL statements with untrusted external data.  You are leaving yourself open to SQL injection.  Please see http://bobby-tables.com/perl.html for examples on how to do it properly.

Answer (score -1):

I think u missed single quote.

change

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO products_features (product_id, feature_id, value) 
        VALUES (".$prodid.", ".$cat_featureid.", ".$dbh->quote($value).") 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=".$dbh->quote($value);
```

to

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO products_features (product_id, feature_id, value) 
        VALUES (".$prodid.", ".$cat_featureid.", '".$dbh->quote($value)."') 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value='".$dbh->quote($value."'");
```

Comment: the above didnt work.. the script throws an error startight away.it normally runs for a while.